# Form submit button not working on mobile in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am learning React JS. I used BootStrap's form in a React JS web application. Submit button is working fine on laptop but not working on mobile devices.

On Mobile, when I touch on the button its border gets highlighted but didn't perform any action. But I have noticed one thing that the HandleSubmit function is not triggering. But if I change onClick tag to `onClick = {alert("Working");}` it works on mobile.

Full code repository is here: https://github.com/AhmadRaza365/iNoteBook

Forms can be found in these components: components/Login.js, Signup.js, AddNote.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error. Basically, forms are working well. The problem was with my localhost API. I was accessing it without port and URL forwarding. And as I am using await function to fetch and post data to API. But API was not connected. As a result, it was not forwarded next.

Answer (score 0):

In Login.js you have a typo: `onClicK` (capital K) vs `onClick`.

But your main problem is that you're mixing up two ways of submitting a form

1. `<form onSubmit={...}>` combined with a `<button type='submit'>` inside the form. In this type of combination, you don't need an `onClick` on the button. Effectively `<button type='submit>`, tells the browser that when someone clicks on the button, go ahead and execute the function you passed to `onSubmit` specified in `<form>`.
2. `<form>` *without* `onSubmit` set on the form element and a button inside the form *without* `type='submit` but only an `onClick` which needs to manually reset the form and do all the subsequent logic associated with given form.

You should choose one or the other for each of your 3 forms – don't use both on a form.

Comment: I have tried both methods. But they didn't work. I think the problem is in handleSubmit function. Because when I use inline function and use alert, it works on mobile.

Comment: You shouldn't mix them. Both work on mobile. Insert `alert("Working")` into your `onSubmit` functions and you'll see them triggered on mobile too. It's just that you're mixing two ways of submitting forms and your alert.js component isn't behaving as you're expecting on mobile.

Comment: I have tried them separately.

Comment: Thank you! I have found the error. Basically, forms are working well. The problem was with my localhost API. I was accessing it without port forwarding.